# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function for onfocusout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had written code for dynamic generated layout in jquery mobile

```
  <input id=' + questions[i].Question.DataType + '-' + questions[i].Question.QuestionId + '-' +  
 QuesDesc + '-' + controlTypevalue + ' name="element_2_2" class="qty form-control required" 
width="100%"   height ="50" maxlength="20" style="width:80%" value="" type="text" 
onfocusout=$.GetID(this.id);>');
```

I am using

```
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

these libraries but I dont know why it is throwing error in first line of html page for this function

Please suggest how to proceed in this case

Comment: What is `$.GetID`? That's not a standard jQuery function.

Comment: what is GetID? where is it defined?

Comment: @Barmar no it is user defined I am using it  $.GetID = function (param) { } to perform some operation

Comment: The error means that it's not defined, so something is not right there.

Comment: @Barmar Could you suggest how should I proceed as I want to use that function on focusout

Comment: There's not enough information here to know why the function isn't defined.

Comment: @Barmar I have declared this function like $.GetID = function (param) { } and called onfocus out like onfocusout=$.GetID(this.id); is there any other info required

Comment: Is your page accessible from the Internet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64771/discussion-between-poojagupta-and-barmar).

Comment: @ No it is not accessible from internet

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Barmer its working fine in fiddle might be some other problem but I am not able to detect it http://jsfiddle.net/B5W4B/

Comment: See this fiddle may be help you :http://jsfiddle.net/B5W4B/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
 layout_input += '<input id="' + questions[i].Question.DataType + '-' + questions[i].Question.QuestionId + '-' + QuesDesc + '-' + controlTypevalue + '" name="element_2_2" class="qty form-control required" width="100%"   height ="50" maxlength="20" style="width:80%" value="" type="text">';

  $('#layout_input').append(layout_input);

  $('.qty').blur(function(){
       alert(this.id)
  })
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it make a difference?

Comment: I  have removed onfocusout=$.GetID(this.id) second thing error in id=' + questions[i].Question.DataType + '-' + questions[i].Question.QuestionId + '-' +  
 QuesDesc + '-' + controlTypevalue + '